# Does Superman wear his marriage ring?

Tags: dc, superman

Does Superman wear his marriage ring?

Didn't really thought of it before, but I've been wondering recently after watching Smallville. He doesn't seem like the type of guy that would take it off, but you'd think he would to maintain his secret identity...

Comment: http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/batman/images/2/27/Superman's_wedding.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120107210341

Comment: Is this specifically addressed at the Smallville show?

Comment: @Valorum That is an incredibly bad image lol. Can't see nuffin. As far as I know, it isn't addressed on Smallville, especially since you never see him in the Superman costume. I was just watching smallville and was curious about it.

Comment: You can clearly see him wearing a wedding ring in that panel.

Comment: @Valorum That is a marriage pic and no you can't. That image is to tiny to even make that out

Comment: Are you viewing this on a mobile? https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJdZv.png

Comment: @Valorum Either way. I mean times when he isn't actually marrying someone. Obviously he is going to be wearing it while he is marrying someone, but does he wear it when he is out on patrol?

Comment: Well, he's not always married. It depends on the continuity :-)

Answer (score 5):

While I can't specifically say every iteration of Superman never wears his wedding ring, the post-Crisis Superman did not wear his. In fact, in the [January 2000](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/comics/2000-post-crisis-reviews/c-review-2000.php?topic=01-sup152) issue, forgetting to remove his ring when he changes becomes a plot point when Jimmy Olsen gets a picture of Superman with the ring on. Jimmy later digitally removes the ring from the picture, I believe.